# How do I pass a variable into mongodb callback?

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to select the distinct values for two fields from my mongodb. Using async.series, I have the following:

```
function getSettings(target){
    var versions = [];
    var result = {};

    function putResults(key, val){
        result[key] = val;
    }
  async.series(
  [
    function(callback){
        db.get(target).distinct('version', function(err, arr){
            if(err) return err;
            versions = arr;
            callback();
        }); //end db call
    },
    function(callback){
        var items;
        for(var i = 0; i<versions.length; i++)
        {
            db.get(target).distinct('instance', {version: versions[i]}, function(err, arr){
                items = arr;
                putResults(versions[i], items);
            }); //end db call
         }
     }
  ], 
  function(err){
         if(err) return err;
         console.log(result);
  }); //end async
}
```

With this code, I get an "undefined" exception on putResults(versions[i], items). I know it's because versions is out of scope. My question is: how do I get it in scope?

Expected result:

```
 result = {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our case better use [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) instead of `series`, and [map](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback), like this

```
function getSettings(target){
  async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
      db.get(target).distinct('version', function (err, versions) {
         callback(err, versions);
      });
    },
    function (versions, callback) {
      async.map(versions, function (version, next) {
        db.get(target).distinct('instance', {version: version}, function (err, items) {
          var result = {};
          result[version] = items;
          next(err, result);
        });
      }, function (err, res) {
        callback(err, res);
      });
    }
  ], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return;
    } 

    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As **Alexander** mentioned in his comment, if you want to pass the values from the first function to the next one, you should use `waterfall` instead of `series`.

As specified in the official documentation regarding `waterfall`:

> Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing
>   their results to the next in the array. However, if any of the tasks
>   pass an error to their own callback, the next function is not
>   executed, and the main callback is immediately called with the error.

If you would like to read more about the various capabilities of async I strongly recommend their official documentation ([LINK](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall)).